# Convert the property names of an object from camel case to sentence case

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Having an array of objects of this form:

```
myData = [{firstName: 'john', lastName: 'y', hairColor: 'black'},
          {firstName: 'mike', lastName: 'x', hairColor: 'green'},
          {firstName: 'alex', lastName: 'z', hairColor: 'brown'}];
```

it must be transformed to this:

```
myData = [{First name: 'john', Last name: 'y', Hair color: 'black'},
          {First name: 'mike', Last name: 'x', Hair color: 'green'},
          {First name: 'alex', Last name: 'z', Hair color: 'brown'}];
```

So, the property value must be converted from camel case to sentence, **firstName** to **First name**.

So I used a function to compute that:

```
function replaceIt(text) {
  const result = text.replace( /([A-Z])/g, " $1" );
  const finalResult = result.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + result.slice(1);
  return finalResult;
}
```

but I don't know how to apply it to the array.

Something like `myData.forEach(a => ... );`

Any ideas?

Comment: You can - "First name" is a valid key name. You just need to wrap it with quote marks.

Comment: Note that to access the properties after being renamed you must use the bracket notation. `myData["First name"]`

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate an object by converting it to `[key, value]` pairs, using `Object.entries()`, mapping the entries, and then convert back to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`.

I've created a `mapKeys` function that accepts a `transformFn`, and updates the object keys accordingly.

```js
const mapKeys = (transormFn, obj) => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key, value]) => [transormFn(key), value])
);

const myData = [{"firstName":"john","lastName":"y","hairColor":"black"},{"firstName":"mike","lastName":"x","hairColor":"green"},{"firstName":"alex","lastName":"z","hairColor":"brown"}];

function replaceIt(text) {
  const result = text.replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $1");
  const finalResult = result.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + result.slice(1).toLowerCase(); // result.slice(1).toLowerCase() should get you the desired form
  return finalResult;
}

const result = myData.map(o => mapKeys(replaceIt, o));

console.log(result);
```

A nice addition by @ScottSauyet is to [curry](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/curry-and-function-composition-2c208d774983) the `mapKeys` function. This saves you the arrow function when mapping the array:

```js
const mapKeys = transormFn => obj => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key, value]) => [transormFn(key), value])
);

const myData = [{"firstName":"john","lastName":"y","hairColor":"black"},{"firstName":"mike","lastName":"x","hairColor":"green"},{"firstName":"alex","lastName":"z","hairColor":"brown"}];

function replaceIt(text) {
  const result = text.replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $1");
  const finalResult = result.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + result.slice(1).toLowerCase(); // result.slice(1).toLowerCase() should get you the desired form
  return finalResult;
}

const result = myData.map(mapKeys(replaceIt));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `First Name` should be `First name` etc

Comment: @Jamiec: The OP posted this replacement function, which didn't match the preferred output, but the question was about how to apply this to an array of objects.  This answers that question admirably.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yep, I missed that this was just from the OP. Its a good answer you're right.

Comment: My own taste would be to curry the main function `mapKeys = (transformFn) => (obj) => ...`, and then be able to easily use the partially applied version: `result = myData .map (mapKeys (replaceIt))`.  But that's a minor concern.

Comment: @Jamiec - thanks for the text correction.

Comment: np. Great answer !

Comment: @ScottSauyet -I've added your curried suggestion as well. Tnx :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `Array.reduce` combined with `Object.entries`:

```js
const newData = myData.map(
  obj => Object.entries(obj)
    .reduce( (acc, [key, value]) => ({
      ...acc,
      [replaceIt(key)]: value,
    }), {})
);
```